# MongoDB installation on aws ec2 server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install mongoDB on ec2 ubuntu server and following this link 
https://optimalbi.com/blog/2017/09/14/how-to-install-mongodb-with-aws-ec2/
but it gives me this error

```
root@ip-172-31-9-20:~# sudo apt update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I tried

```
sudo sed -i -e '1d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

But then it gave the following error -

```
E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use below command to check any bad characters:
`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list`

Answer (score 0):

If your ubuntu version is 18.04, you need to put a different syntax there. You need to delete the previous file.

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

Then you can do `sudo apt update`